# Convert string to datetime and then back to string

Tags: c#, datetime-format

Hi I am trying to convert a string to date time and then back to a string. This is my code.

```
try
{
    string dt = "19/9/13";
   DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string msg = ex.Message;
}
```

and also tried `Convert.ToDateTime(dt.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

I am getting this error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`. can any one give a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what culture you are using, however, by default it's date-separator is used. So if you for example use `.` as separator that won't work.

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dt DateTime.ParseExact("19/9/13", "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: But I am getting this error 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'InvariantInfo'

Comment: @Vijesh: sorry, that was a typo. Corrected. It's of course `InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have:

```
string time = "19/9/13";

DateTime resds =DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd/M/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string datet = resds.ToShortDateString();
```

[DateTime.ParseExact documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing is true. The problem is the datetime because your computer supports another datetime format. It tries to get 19 as a month - and it throws this exception.

Probably if you write this it will work:

```
string dt = "9/19/13";
```

Or just change your computer settings to:  dd/MMM/YYYY format.

Answer (score 1):

try with `DateTime.ParseExact` :

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dt.ToString(), "dd/M/yy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: `null` will also use the current culture. If it's date separator is `!= /` it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd/M/yy").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And take a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert.ToDateTime()` to convert string into date.. and then date to string use `ToString()`

```
string dt = "19/9/13";
Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
```